# Homotopy with paths and inverse paths and a counterexample

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, examples-counterexamples, homotopy-theory

Exercise 3.6 Rotman

> (i) If $f\simeq g$ rel $I^\circ$ (where $I^\circ$ means $\{0,1\}$, the boundary of $I$), then $f^{-1}\simeq g^{-1}$ rel $I^\circ$, where $f$ and $g$ are paths in $X$.
>
> (ii) If $f$ and $g$ are paths in $X$ with $\omega(f)=\alpha(g)$ then $(f*g)^{-1}=g^{-1}*f^{-1}$.
>
> (iii) Give an example of a closed path $f$ where $f*f^{-1}\neq f^{-1}*f$ .
>
> (iv) Show that if $\alpha(f)=p$ and $f$ is not constant then $i_p*f\neq f$.

Attempts to each of them

(i) Consider $H:f\simeq g$ rel $I^\circ$ a relative homotopy. We want $G:f^{-1}\simeq g^{-1}$ rel $I^\circ.$

If we draw a "triangular" diagram from $I\times I\to X, I\times I\to I\times I, I\times I \to X$ under $G,(s,t)\mapsto(1-s,t),H$, respectively, we find that $G=H\circ(1-s,t).$ This indeed yields to $G:f^{-1}\simeq g^{-1}$ rel $I.$

(ii) I do not know how to write $(f*g)^{-1}$ explicitly to try to find similarities with the right hand side $g^{-1}*f^{-1}$.

(iii) How can I come up with a counterexample such that $(f*g)^{-1}=g^{-1}*f^{-1}$?

(iv) By contradiction.

Suppose $i_p*f= f.$

Thus $f(t)=i_p*f(t)=\begin{cases}i_p(2t),0\le t\le\frac 12\\ f(2t-1),\frac 12\le t,\le 1 \end{cases}$

If $t=\frac 12$, then $f(t)=f(\frac 12)=f(0)=i_p(1)=1!$ because $f$ is not constant.

Therefore $i_p*f\neq f$.

Could someone please check my attempts and help me with (ii) and (iii)?

Thank you.

Comment: What are the domain and codomain of $f$? And is $I$ a subspace of the domain? Normally we talk about homotopies relative to a subspace, for instance if we have $A\subseteq X$ we can talk about homotopies between maps $X \to Y$ rel $A$.

Comment: By definition of path, $f:I\to X$ where $I=[0,1]$ and $X$ is a topological space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution to (i) seems fine to me!

(ii) Write it explicitly as

$$
(f*g)^{-1}(t)=(f*g)(1-t)=\begin{cases}
f(2-2t)\quad\text{if $1-t\leq\frac12$}\\
g(2-2t-1)\quad\text{if $1-t\geq\frac12$}\end{cases}=\begin{cases}
g(1-2t)\quad\text{if $t\leq\frac12$}\\
f(2-2t)\quad\text{if $t\geq\frac12$}\end{cases}.
$$

(iii) Simply a circle, because moving clockwise then counterclockwise is not the same as vice versa. In fact, every closed path $f$ such that $f^{-1}\neq f$ will do. Because if $f^{-1}(t)\neq f(t)$ then $(f^{-1}*f)(\frac12t)\neq(f*f^{-1})(\frac12t)$. So say $f(t)=(\cos 2\pi t,\sin 2\pi t)$ -- this is my personal favorite example.

(iv) I think you have a good idea, but I don't get your proof. $i_p(1)=1$? My (probably similar) idea: from $f([0,\frac12])=\{p\}$ it follows that $f([\frac12,\frac34])=\{p\}$ and thus $f([\frac34,\frac78])=\{p\}$ and so on. You could say that $i_p*f=f$ means that $f$ on $[\frac12,1]$ is the same as $f$ on $I$. But this implies that whatever $f$ does, $f$ does it again twice as close to $t=1$. That's where the argument comes from. Assuming that the topological space is Hausdorff, $f([0,1))=\{p\}$ contradicts the fact that $f$ is not constant.

Comment: For (ii) I did arrive to $(f*g)^{-1}(t)=\begin{cases}
f(2-2t)\quad\text{if $t\leq\frac12$}\\
g(1-2t)\quad\text{if $t\geq\frac12$}\end{cases}$ and $(g^{-1}*f^{-1})(t)=\begin{cases} g(1-2t),\quad t\le\frac 12\\ f(2-2t),\quad t\ge\frac  12\end{cases}$. How could I pass $f$ to the place of $g$ ?

Comment: For (iv) Why can we assume that $X$ is Hausdorff ?

Comment: I now see that we both made the same mistake in expanding $(f*g)^{-1}$. ;) I edited the answer so you should be able to see it there. As to answer your other comment: you *have* to make some extra assumption, because if $X$ has the trivial topology then $f([0,1))=\{p\},f(1)\neq p$ yields a counterexample to (iv). It is sufficient to ask that $X$ satisfies the $T_1$ axiom, i.e. for all $p\neq q\in X$ there is a neighborhood of $p$ that doesn't contain $q$.

Comment: I see, now is equal to the RHS : ) For (iv), why from $f([0,\frac12])=\{p\}$ it follows that $f([\frac12,\frac34])=\{p\}$ and so on ?

Comment: For $t\leq\frac14$ we have $f(\frac12+t)=(i_p*f)(\frac12+t)=f(2(\frac12+t)-1)=f(2t)=p$. Continue in a similar manner.

Comment: Why for $t\le\frac 14$ we have $f(\frac 12+t)$ ? I feel like I am missing something trivial, I cannot figure it out what is it

Comment: I find it super that you keep asking until you fully understand. You asked why $f([\frac12,\frac34])=\{p\}$, and to show this in my previous comment, I calculated $f(u)$ for $u\in[\frac12,\frac34]$, or equivalently $f(\frac12+t)$ for $t\leq\frac14$. Indeed it ended up with $p$. You can continue to prove that $f([\frac34,\frac78])=\{p\}$ like for $t\leq\frac18$ we have $f(\frac34+t)=(i_p*f)(\frac34+t)=f(2(\frac34+t)-1)=f(\frac12+2t)=p$ because $\frac12+2t\in[\frac12,\frac34]$. Induction can complete the proof in a rigorous style, but I would just say that it goes on like that.

Comment: I also improved the description in (iv) in the answer

Comment: Thanks Paul. One last question could you improve more details in (iii) please?